асинхронный запрос внутри цикла
Имеется код:
  const arr = [1,2,4,5,7]
  const prom = async (props) => {
    const result = await Proff767.find({ proff: props });
    return result;
  };

  for (const data of arr) {
    console.log(1);
    const filtredArr = el.filter((f) => f.num === data);
    for (let k = 0; k <= filtredArr.length - 1; k += 1) {
      filtredArr[k].number = strIndex++;
      sheet.addRow(filtredArr[k]);
      if (k === 0 && filtredArr[k].proff) {
        console.log(2);
        prom(filtredArr[0].proff).then((e) => {
          for (const value of e) {
            console.log(3);
            sheet.addRow(value);
          }
        });
        console.log(4);
      }
    }
  }

В нем присутствует запрос к БД Proff767.find, и этот запрос отстает от основного кода. Где я ошибся?
По консоль логам вывод:
1
2
4
3
Пишу на экспрессе.

Потеряли await перед prom. Если этот код синхронный, придется перестраивать логику. Или быстрый лайф хах, весь for оберните в асинхронную фукнцию и вызовите, а внутри добавьте await

@SwaD Ваш лайф Хак помог отчасти, консоль логи теперь выводятся верно, а вот sheet.addRow(value); в последнем цикле не срабатывает почему-то

Это уже к другой области, т.к. не понятно, что за el и что в нем содержится. Обертка вашего кода в фукнцию или добавление await не могло поломать логику и данные

@SwaD согласен с Вами, sheet.addRow(value) это из  библиотеки exceljs. По поводу массива, то все данные корректно приходят
